# Error when trying to install `r` in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, r

I'm getting the following error when trying to `sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev`:
 [image]

Comment: Please try to repair your package system with `sudo apt -f install` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and post their outputs if they don't solve your problem.

Comment: After doing above still facing the same issue

Comment: The try reinstalling: `sudo apt --reinstall install r-base r-base-dev`

Comment: Packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.23) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
               Depends: libgomp1 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
               Depends: liblapack3 but it is not going to be installed or
                        liblapack.so.3
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems.

Comment: Same issue i am getting after reinstallation also.

Comment: How about installing them all together? `sudo apt install r-base r-base-cor r-base-dev r-recommended gfortran liblapack-dev libicu-dev`

Comment: Why is it trying to install version 3.4.1-2xenial0 on trusty? Have you added a xenial PPA or added xenial repos to your sources list?